# Where is the seed log for Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I run db:seed:all command, it gives me this error:

```
Seed file failed with error: Validation error
```

How can I see the log of which validation that got error in Sequelize?

Comment: I was looking for it too, finded how?

Comment: haven't found anything yet. end up testing it one file by one file. pain in the ass

Answer (score 30):

You can see the degub info by using the `--debug` option to the command, like:

```
$ sequelize db:seed:all --debug
```

this option, and others can be found by typing:

```
$ sequelize db:seed:all --help
```

The seed log for Sequelize can be activated by setting true to the logging property of the sequelize config.js, as follow:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "logging": true,
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "logging": true,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "logging": false,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

The default configuration file can be found here: [Default configuration file for sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#configuration).

hope this helps :D